# The render loop freezes temporarly at first "contact" of the camera frustum with multiple meshes

Tags: performance, three.js

I have a basic scene into wich I am loading objects using the JSONLoader. The objects themselves have very small footprint, for example: milk carton: 560kb with textures, 34 kb json file.

When rendering, let's say 10 new objects, if I orbit the camera to bring them into view, the animation loop freezes for a second or so. After this first freeze, the camera orbits smoothly no matter how many objects. Loading dynamically the objects would be a solution, but for my specific use case, I still need to load at least 50 objects at first load.

**Update** - I have added the preload functions I use in my production project, and I also added 21 different models just to illustrate my specific scenario. I have tried the following solution:

- preloading the json files,
- reading the source path to the textures,
- loading them with texture loader,
- overwritting the maps of the json material objects with the preloaded textures,
- finally releasing the objects into scene. The same behavior occurs again.

Try to click the setCamera link to se how laggy it is. I need to cut this lag to 0ms. Thanks for support!

**Working demo:** http://demo.adrianmoisa.ro/flexikom-loader/ First try to orbit the camera up and down to check it's working ok, then left and right. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for not posting an example in the first place. The project has allready grown very much and it wasn't clear wich parts to cut into an example, however I have found an early version of my project and I modified it to exibit the described behavior. Example is posted above. Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: I didn't continued with the project until finish, but I will restart work and I still have to find an answer for this issue. I recall that I loaded all objects in scene, put the camera in a far away position in order to catch all objects in frustrum. When all it was finished I released the camera to normal position and started main loop. However, this solution increased the initial loading time. I remember not being too happy with the results. No frame freezing though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see you are loading the same object 10 times, creating 10 meshes that are all the same. All use the same geometry and the same material. This is where your lag comes from. Both from the loading (asynchronous request to the server) and the object creation.

What you need to do is to load one object and create one material that you will assign to the object. Then you `clone()` the object 10 times assigning the different position that you want to each cloned object.

Comment: That is a very good bit of advice which I will use for the 4 cloned meshes that am I am duplicating in order to obtain some special FX in my project (outline, highlight, tooltip). However this still leaves me with the problem of loading 50 different models simultaneously in my production project, which have different meshes and textures. That still leaves me with the same lag at first camera frustrum intersection. Thank you!

Comment: Just a small note: I see that the objects leave shadow on the ground plane , and if I slowly turn the camera towards the right where the objects are situated animation is smoth untill the first object hits the camera frustum. Then I have the lag, than again it works ok.

Comment: yes but now you are asking a total different question. you have to design your page knowing that lag will exist. data are send to the GPU when an object comes into view.

Comment: Well, that is true, but it seems to me that this lag it's huge for just 10 objects with very low poly count. Is there anything that can be done to optimize? I have read about merge geometry, but i think it's not an option for me if i want to have independt motion for separate objects in scene.

Comment: the example you offered is designed wrong and I did offer how you can fix it. On the other hand I also experienced the lag that you mention but it was not close to a second; rather it was much less. so your network connection could also be a problem (only when things are loading)

Comment: Please take a look at the updated demo. I tried the preloading solution but still it doesn't remove the lag. Thank you!

Comment: let me call lag1 the lag from loading the objects and lag2 the lag from sending the data to the GPU. Before you were seeing both lags (not at the same time). Now you only have lag2 which is trickier as it happens when the objects come into view because that is when the new data is transferred to the GPU. So what you need to do is move the loading to the GPU to the same location where page loading happens. To do that you need to somehow have those elements in your viewport at page loading time with maybe a second camera with a very small viewport.

Comment: I tried your stated solution previously but I think I messed the texture preloading in my production code and that made it lag frustratingly long. I'll try to fix it and check if the lag still exceeds more than 5 secs. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Sorry for not returning an update answer. I am still working on the project, there are many tasks and I posponed this one untill I finish other previous tasks on the project. I will digg into it next week to see if things get better. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Gaitat is correct that you should not be loading the same object 10 times. But I think the lag is directly related to the textures.
You should load the textures outside of the loop.
How it is now, you are loading 30 textures onto the gpu when you could be just loading 2 (at least I think this is how it is working).
Profiling the page shows that `texture2D` is taking a lot of time.
I am almost certain that this will stop the lag.

Comment: I have updated the demo with a preload function, and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: As the new version has more textures, my answer is no longer relevant.